# std::sort() does not look for global operator<() defined

Tags: c++

Consider a code below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    std::string str;
};

inline bool operator<(Foo const& lhs, Foo const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.str > rhs.str;                                                   
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> v = {{"abc"}, {"def"}};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

The problem is that **this works perfectly without any problems.**

But in my production code:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Does NOT work; but using the code below DOES work:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), &::operator<);
```

So what is happening here? I totally have no clue to this problem.

I'm suspecting that the ADL is doing something bad with namespaces defined in my production code.

Comment: This means that your example is non-representative. What exactly are you storing in your `v` in your production code? What type? Is that type by any chance declared inside some namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not providing enough information. However, an educated guess would be that your actual code involves namespaces and you are experiencing an ordinary ADL (argument-dependent lookup) failure.

If the type stored in `v` is not a member of global namespace, then the compiler is not supposed to unconditionally search the entire global namespace for comparison operator.

The compiler will perform regular lookup for `operator <` from the point of definition of `std::sort`, which obviously will not find your global `operator <` (since `std::sort` is defined somewhere in one of the standard library files).

The compiler will also perform ADL in namespaces associated with the type being compared. You are not telling us much about that type, but I'd guess that that type is not defined in the global namespace. For this reason global namespace is not nominated for ADL and the operator is not found.

Here a simple example that won't compile for the very same reason

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

namespace N {
  struct S { int i = 0; };
}

bool operator <(const N::S &lhs, const N::S &rhs)
{
  return lhs.i < rhs.i;
}

int main()
{
  N::S a[10];
  std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
}
```

The compiler is not supposed to find the global `operator <` even though it is right there in plain sight.

Comment: Your guess seems perfectly correct. I think I've been totally messed up with the namespaces...